Elasticsearch k-NN Search Error: "Invalid type: expecting [_doc] but got [_knn_search]" using python

Elasticsearch k-NN Search Error: "Invalid type: expecting [_doc] but got [_knn_search]"
I'm working on a project where I need to perform a k-nearest neighbors (k-NN) search using Elasticsearch. The idea is to take an input query, encode it into a vector using Sentence-Transformers, and then search for the most similar entries in the Elasticsearch index based on this vector. However, I'm encountering an error when trying to execute the k-NN search.
Code
Here's the code I'm using:
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer

def search_function(query):
    es = Elasticsearch('http://3.110.155.4:9200/')

    model = SentenceTransformer("all-mpnet-base-v2")
    vector_of_input_keyword = model.encode(query)

    knn_query = {
        "field": "DescriptionVector",
        "query_vector": vector_of_input_keyword,
        "k": 10,
        "num_candidates": 100,
    }

    res = es.knn_search(index="house_6", knn=knn_query, _source=["id", "price", "bedroom", "bathroom", "sqft", "builtArea", "location_name"])
    
    return res["hits"]["hits"]

input_query = input("Enter query to search: ")
print("Search results:")
print(search_function(input_query))

Index Mappings
The mappings for my Elasticsearch index are defined as follows:
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "id": { "type": "long" },
      "price": { "type": "long" },
      "bedroom": { "type": "long" },
      "bathroom": { "type": "long" },
      "sqft": { "type": "long" },
      "builtArea": { "type": "long" },
      "location_name": { "type": "text" },
      "description": { "type": "text" },
      "DescriptionVector": {
        "type": "dense_vector",
        "dims": 768,
        "index": true,
        "similarity": "l2_norm"
      }
    }
  }
}

Error
When I run the code, I encounter the following error:
elasticsearch.BadRequestError: BadRequestError(400, 'illegal_argument_exception', 'Invalid type: expecting [_doc] but got [_knn_search]')

Additional Details

Elasticsearch Version: 7.10.2
Elasticsearch Python Client Version: 7.10.0
Sentence-Transformers Version: 2.1.0

Things I've Tried

Checked Index and Mappings: Verified that the index and mappings were created successfully.
Server Accessibility: Ensured that the Elasticsearch server is running and accessible.
Compatibility Check: Confirmed that the knn_search method is available in the version of Elasticsearch I’m using.

Question
How can I resolve this error and perform a k-NN search correctly using Elasticsearch? Is there something I'm missing in my setup or code?
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

